# Getting error while converting byte array to image asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

i have one use case, to convert byte array to image.How to do it. I have done some RND but getting error from below code.

```
public static bool IsValidImage(byte[] bytes)
{
try
{
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Please Suggest me

Comment: `getting error from below code` What is the error/exception you got while the stream does not have a valid image format?

Comment: Error i am getting is parameter is
image.fromstream(ms) parameter is not valid

Comment: Are you sure that the method `IsValidImage` does not return false?